# Swift string interpolation produces string that takes very long to insert in a dictionary

Tags: swift, nsstring, foundation

Under some conditions, string interpolation produces a string that is way slower to use as a dictionary key than a string produced with `String(format:)`. Take the following code:

```
var map = [String: String]()
let start = Date()
for _ in 0..<100000 {
    var s = "asdf"
    s = (s as NSString).appendingPathComponent("")
    s = transform(s)
    s = (s as NSString).substring(from: 1)
    map[s] = s
}
print(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)

func transform(_ s: String) -> String {
    return "\(s)/\(s)"
//    return String(format: "%@/%@", s, s)
}
```

On my Mac I get the time interval 0.69 seconds printed out in the console (when using the string interpolation), but when commenting out line 13 and uncommenting line 14 (so that we use `String(format:)`) I get a 0.33 seconds time interval, less than half the time. Curiously, whenever uncommenting line 5 or line 7, string interpolation is faster. Also, when commenting out line 8 (`map[s] = s`), the version with the string interpolation is faster than the one with `String(format:)`.

This took me quite a lot of time to figure out, since I would expect both methods to produce the same kind of string, but string interpolation to be always faster. Does anybody know why?

Comment: They do not create the same kind of String. An NSString-backed String is not the same thing as a native Swift String; they just have the same interface. At various points, they have to convert. @matt's answer is correct. Don't force the system to make NSString-backed Strings, and then force it to convert those back to Character-backed Strings. Those are not free operations.

Comment: If you want to explore this further, study the source, and particularly _StringGuts. Start here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift and then here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringGuts.swift  Swift heavily optimizes over different storage backends to avoid conversions. When you force a conversion, you can add a lot of cost. You avoid that by just using String, and not using `as NSString`.

Comment: Just replacing the `substring(from: 1)` line with `s = String(s.dropFirst())` will dramatically speed things up.

Comment: Thanks, I get that the context switch is a problem. What still doesn't make sense is that the two variants inside the `transform()` function both use a Swift String, still one is faster to insert into the dictionary than the other.

Comment: "Both use a Swift String" is misunderstanding what it means to have an NSString-backed String. A Swift String can be backed several ways. It isn't necessarily converted at the point of `as`; it just has different Guts. For hashes to be consistent, however, you're going to have to make sure that the string is evaluated in a consistent form (which, depending on several factors, could involve converting an UTF-16 NSString into UTF-8). The point is "String" is an interface, not an implementation. And forcing conflicting implementations to work together is expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the string interpolation vs the format string *per se* that takes time, and it has basically nothing to do with the dictionary insertion.

The significant thing is *the amount of context switching* between String and NSString that the rest of the code requires.

To see that, comment out the two lines that contain `(s as NSString)`. Now you'll find that the format string version takes considerably longer than the string interpolation. That's because the format string introduces a context switch.

With your original code, sticking a String operation in the middle of two NSString operations means there are *three* pairs of context switches. That's the source of the slowness. In other words, if you're going to switch to NSString at all, do *all NSString stuff* until you're done, so there is just one context switch in one direction and one context switch back in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what you say definitely makes sense. What I wanted to point out is that when commenting out line 8 (`map[s] = s`), the version with the string interpolation is faster than the one with `String(format:)`, so the dictionary insertion definitely plays a role here. I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: Cool, but you are not measuring at that level of granularity. Deleting the `map` line made very little difference in my tests, whereas it is clear that every context switch is a quantum.

Comment: Thanks, I get that the context switch is a problem. What still doesn't make sense is that the two variants inside the `transform()` function both use a Swift String, still one is faster to insert into the dictionary than the other.

Comment: Because, as I explained, `String(format:)` is a Cocoa Objective-C function, but simple string interpolation is a Swift function. Therefore if we are already an NSString at the time `transform` is called, `String(format:)` is faster because there is no context switch, but if we are a Swift String, string interpolation is faster because there is no context switch.

Comment: I suspect that some of the confusion is that the OP may be reading "context switch" as a one-time conversion that happens at the `as` rather than something that happens repeatedly if the StringGuts mismatch.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me that `String(format:)` is a Cocoa Objective-C function, in this case your explanation makes sense. It looks like it should be a native Swift `String` function since it doesn't have the `NS` prefix. Is this documented somewhere or how can I differentiate between Swift and Objective-C functions?

Comment: The easiest way is to try to compile your code in the absence of Foundation. Whip out a playground and do _not_ import UIKit or Foundation. If your code compiles, it is pure Swift. If not, it is Cocoa Foundation code, rooted in Objective-C. — Another way is to examine NSString. If a String method also exists in NSString, it is an NSString method, acquired by String only thanks to bridging.